# Click once deployment to a ISP hosted Server (ISP is Lunarpages in this case)

Tags: deployment, clickonce, hosted

I know this has some crossover to Serverfault.com but the advice on meta.stackoverflow was to ask it here (first) as it requires a .NET dev to answer more than likely.

I am having some problems publishing to my website a Click Once App, I am getting an error message saying (something like) IIS not running, I'm not currently at home to give an exact error message, i'll edit later if it is required to answer this question.

My ISP is lunarpages the plan I am on is [this one](http://www.lunarpages.com/windows-hosting/) IIS is definitely running as I have BlogEngine.NET running just fine. Anyone know what is required configuration wise (both server and client) to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The files that the ClickOnce publish create can be run on just about any web environment (include Apache/Linux.) It simply generates an html page along with the application manifest and your application files. Maybe you can deploy to a local folder and upload the files to the server?

Comment: I'll give that a go. Doesn't that affect the signing of the manifest though?

Comment: It shouldn't affect it. The ClickOnce is file driven. When it was first released there were several people asking the question at the conference I was at and this was mentioned.